# Which of these is the proper convention?

Tags: latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between lon and lng](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24690/difference-between-lon-and-lng)

I run over these three abbreviations:

- "lat/lon"
- "lat/long"
- "lat/lng"

Are they equal?

Comment: this question is similar to [Difference between lon and lng](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24690/difference-between-lon-and-lng/24696#24696).

Answer (score 8):

Same, equivalent terms. lat/long is probably the most common, but of course "long" is a reserved word / data type in many programming languages, so you'll find other ways to shorten longitude.

In some contexts, GIS people will use long/lat (i.e. reverse order), since this is the normal X/Y coordinate reference system for a Cartesian plane.